# How to check if select query is returning more than one value in java

Tags: java

I am executing a select query through preparedstatment, now I have to raise an exception in basis of if resultset contains more than one value,so my question is how to determine that rs is returning multiple values.?

Comment: how do you run your db requests? jdbc? hibernate? crystal sphere?

Comment: The code ! Post the code !

Answer (score 3):

try this:

```
ResultSet lResult = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT A,B,C FROM YOURTABLE");
boolean lMoreThanOne = lResult.first() && lResult.next();
```

Comment: thnnx,wl let u know,if any issue